# How to remove blank lines from HTML

Tags: php, html

I want to remove the blank lines between my html and PHP code when I view source it you can see where the PHP code goes I want to change this

```
   <table>
         <tr>
            <th align='right'>Service Area:</th>
            <th align='right'>Union</th>

            <th align='right'>South Carolina</th>


         </tr>
   </table>
```

to this

```
       <table>
         <tr>
            <th align='right'>Service Area:</th>
            <th align='right'>Union</th>
            <th align='right'>South Carolina</th>
         </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: Not whitespaces but blank lines!?

Comment: browsers dont care, why do you?

Comment: He probably don't want visitors to look up the source code and find out where are the PHP parts

Comment: @PhiterFernandes that makes no sense

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I am new to hand coding and I have looked a several projects it was just a need to know... Not that it mattered but I wanted to know.

Comment: you should have been posting (PHP) "source" code and not rendered HTML

Comment: You could try what I'm showing in my answer. CodeiSir's answer works but you must do it all manually. Using buffer does the job automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first PHP-Tags is how you should not to it, and the second is how you should place them to avoid blank lines:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th align='right'>Service Area:</th>
    <th align='right'>Union</th>
<?php
 // like this you will get a blank line
?>
    <th align='right'>South Carolina</th><?php
 // likes this you will only get one new line
?>
  </tr>
</table>
```